# On Android, how do I use previous Activity's screen as my new Activity's background without translucent background turning black?

Tags: android, android-activity, background

Currently I'm using translucent background which allows for the new Activity to use the previous Activity's screen as the background.  However, if I press home and then return to the activity, the translucent background becomes black.  Is there a way to avoid the background from turning black?

Comment: Have a default background that won't be black, to use when your program is started directly, not from another activity?

Comment: I think it is impossible, I am also searching for it

Comment: yeah, I agree CapDroid. I think it's impossible because the translucent activity never owned the background, so after switching to the launcher activity and back, that previous background was loss. Also, android don't let us get screen captures for security reasons. I was just hoping there's a way to startactivity with the current screen as the background, but I guess we can only use translucent which has the limitation.

Comment: @EddieH I suggest that you post the code you are using because what you are trying to do is working with the answers below. I.e. no black screen returning with home. What's the API level?

Comment: @rochdev thanks, I trust you, i'll investigate different API level and what I'm doing differently. I'm using Android 1.6.
`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity android:name="com.eddiehsu.mathgame.library.MainMenu" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
  </intent-filter>
</activity>`

Comment: `<activity android:name="com.eddiehsu.mathgame.library.MathGame" android:theme="@style/Theme.NoBackground" /> 
  <activity android:name="com.eddiehsu.mathgame.library.EndMenu" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />` 
the translucent is on the EndMenu activity that I care for, maybe let me change everything to translucent and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a theme to make any activity translucent.

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" ..>
    ..
</activity>
```

This will make the background for the activity translucent also when you return to it. But obviously you can't control the background of the activity behind it.

Comment: just to clarify, this is my situation: if I go from activity 1, to activity 2 （activity 2 is translucent and uses activity 1 as the background), then from activity 2, press home, and then return back into the app which is activity 2, but it no longer uses activity 1 as the background and instead have a black background. when you say "also when you return to it", does that mean it does not suppose to be black in my situation?

Comment: I just tested this on three devices, 1.6 - 2.2, with the activity layout you posted above. From A->B->C where C is translucent with B's background. Clicked on Home. Held Home and returned to C, still with B's background.

Comment: ahhh I see, i changed B to a regular activity and indeed C is now showing the translucent background even after home. the problem was that I was using AndEngine, a game engine for B, and it manages its own background through code. i'll look into this further on the andengine boards, but thanks a lot for your help rochdev!

Answer (score 0):

using

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

in your activity tag in the manifest file.

Comment: sorry, but I think you missed the real question:
"However, if I press home and then return to the activity, the translucent background becomes black. Is there a way to avoid the background from turning black?"